# Passing configuration parameters from apache.conf to custom apache C module?

Tags: c, apache

Is there any mechanism in the Apache httpd framework that would allow me to pass custom parameters from the Apache configuration file to a custom Apache module (written using the C API)?  I really only need key/value pairs.

Something like in conf file:

```
ConfigParameter foo bar
```

And then in the code:

```
string foo = GetApacheConfigParameter("foo"); // = "bar"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; not directly. A dirty hack would be

```
SetEnv foo bar
```

in the config file - and a

```
char * bar = getenv("foo");
```

in your module. Anything beyond that requires the use of a proper structure on a per directory, server, etc. Normally that structure would contain a lot of specific things. In your case it would just be a single table.

So somewhat clean way would be to simply use a table - and leave it at that:

```
 static const command_rec xxx_cmds[] = {
    AP_INIT_TAKE2("ConfigParameter", add_configparam, NULL, RSRC_CONF,
              "Arbitrary key value pair"),
   {NULL}
};

 static void * create_dir_config(apr_pool_t *p, char *dirspec ) {
    return ap_table_palloc(p);
 }

 static const char *add_configparam(cmd_parms *cmd, void *mconfig,   
                               char *key, char *val) 
 {
    ap_table_t *pairs = (ap_table_rec *) mconfig;
    ap_table_set(pairs, key, val);
    return NULL;
 }

 AP_DECLARE_MODULE(xxxx_module) =
 {
   STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
   xxx_create_dir_config,    /* per-directory config creator */
   ...
   xxx_cmds,                 /* command table */
```

and then, everywhere where you want to use this do:

```
apr_table_t * pairs =  (apr_table_p *) ap_get_module_config(r->request_config, &xxxx_module);
```

or

```
 apr_table_t * pairs =  ap_get_module_config(s->module_config, &xxxx_module);
```

depending on where it us used - and then use:

```
char * bar = apr_table_get(pairs,"foo");
```

or similar. See mod_example_hooks and the various our_* calls to get a pointer. Above example leaves out configs on server level and merging of configs. Add those if you need them - there is a corresponding merge call for tables. mod_alias.c et.al. have good examples.

Comment: Your first solution (SetEnv) doesn't work because it doesn't seem to be executed by the time the childinit hook is run in my module.  I ended up solving this problem by creating a seperate config file for my module.